# Chrome remote debugging on Arch Linux: Android device not detected

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, archlinux

I'm trying to remote debug a mobile website running on Chrome on an Anroid device from my Arch Linux computer.

However, after following the [instruction for remote debugging Android devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), my Android device isn't detected by Chrome when I connect it.

Why doesn't Chrome detect my device?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the `gvfs-mtp` package on Arch Linux.

This package is needed for remote debugging Android devices, as well as for mounting Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

For file managers that use **GVFS (GNOME Files)**, install **gvfs-mtp** for MTP or gvfs-gphoto2 for PTP support.

For file managers that use **KIO (KDE's Dolphin)**, MTP support is included in **kio-extras**.

For more details, refer to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP